# I gave 12V to my USB port on my laptop G50 70 i3 4th gen and now it's not working

Tags: laptop, power

I built a DIY cooler station for my laptop laptop which features both USB powered as well as 12V - 20V DC powered jack.

I knew from the start that I that it would be possible to accidentally power both the power inputs together, and today I did exactly that and powered the fan with 12V DC and at the same time it was also connected to my laptop and it went out.

I don't know what could be possibly wrong.

Comment: Did you damage the laptop or the cooler or both?

Comment: It was connected to the laptop's USB port? Or connected to the laptop's power jack? What exactly went out?

Answer (score 1):

You probably fried the USB controller chip, or at least 1 port on it.

Maybe more.

Next time visit electronics.stackexchange.com in advance.

"How do I avoid damaging my computer when I attach a 12-20v diy cooler?"

You could have found out diodes would have prevented electricity from back flowing to your computer.  Also you can usually buy a bag of diodes for approx $1.

If your CPU and RAM are undamaged, a new motherboard is usually 200-380 USD new.

Comment: but even if the usb is fried the laptop must atleast start a bit. i found out on internet my CMOS may be fried but it is RAM for my lappy. so even if RAM is fried my laptop should atleast start for a while and go off(as  i think).

Comment: @AdeshKumar - You could have damaged more than just the USB circuitry when you provided that 12 volts.  I suggest you take it to a repair shop, one that has a circuit diagram, who can diagnose what exactly is fried and isn't fried.

Comment: @Ramhound  I agree, more than the USB is damaged. It is highly likely they fried the whole motherboard, and even if you only fried part of it the **only** solution is to replace the whole motherboard.  And find a laptop motherboard is at least 3x harder because the holes for the all the ports have to line up.  Usually there is only 1 or 2 motherboards that actually fit a specific laptop.